# javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob incompatible with oracle.sql.BLOB

Tags: oracle, websphere, blob, batch-processing, classcastexception

I just created the IBM XD Grid data model in Oracle 12c DB and when I submit a job, the server throws the following error (with Derby DB works fine but I need to configure a production environment):

I have seen a TechNote (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM61715) related with this issue but no fix/solution is provided.

In this TechNote says "***The fix for this APAR is currently targeted for inclusion in fix pack 8.0.0.2***" but I am working with WAS **8.5.5.4**

The stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob incompatible with oracle.sql.BLOB
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setBlob(OraclePreparedStatement.java:6795)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.setBlob(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:1528)
    at com.ibm.ws.gridcontainer.persistence.LocalJobStatusDataStoreImpl.update(LocalJobStatusDataStoreImpl.java:524)
    at com.ibm.ws.gridcontainer.services.impl.WASJDBCPersistenceServiceImpl._updateJobStatus(WASJDBCPersistenceServiceImpl.java:284)
    at com.ibm.ws.gridcontainer.services.impl.AbstractPersistenceManagerImpl.updateData(AbstractPersistenceManagerImpl.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.gridcontainer.services.impl.JobStatusManagerImpl.updateContextData(JobStatusManagerImpl.java:887)
    at com.ibm.ws.gridcontainer.batch.checkpoint.CheckpointMgr._updateContextData(CheckpointMgr.java:510)
    at com.ibm.ws.gridcontainer.batch.checkpoint.CheckpointMgr.prepareForCheckpoint(CheckpointMgr.java:354)
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, we found the problem that caused this error: the WAS profile was corrupted, we created at the beginning with Derby DB and then we moved it to Oracle.

If we create a new profile with Oracle it works fine.

The PMR has been closed.